# Delete helm with Chart name but not with Release name

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I deployed my apps using helm. Mistakenly I put the same helm release name. Now how can I delete the specific deployment for e.g. first one with chart `my-chart-1.0.0`.

```
$ helm ls

NAME                REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART               NAMESPACE
appname         1           Mon Oct  1 10:36:17 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-1.0.0      default
appname         1           Mon Sep 10 17:18:49 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-2.0.0      default
appname         1           Mon Sep 10 18:18:49 2018    DEPLOYED    my-chart-3.0.0      default
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this should help:

`helm delete $(helm ls | awk '$9 ~ /SEARCH/ { print $1 }')`

Replace `SEARCH` with any chart pattern, in your case `my-chart-1.0.0`.
I would also add a `--dry-run` and check if this is indeed the deployment you want to remove.

You can read the Helm documentation regarding [helm delete](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-delete).